# How to initialize a jQuery widget like this: var newMap = xgis.map('#map', options);

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, openlayers, gis

Maybe this question has already been posted here, but I searched and I didn't find the detailed case that I want.

I have GIS API working on top of OpenLayers. I have a jQuery widget, called "xgis", that creates the OpenLayers Map.

The widget is defined like this:

```
$.widget('xgis.xgis', {
    options: {
        opt1: true,
        opt2: [],
        opt3: ''
    },
    method1: function() {
        ...
    },
    method2 ...,
    ...
});
```

When I want to create a map, I simply do this:

```
var newMap = $('#map').xgis(options);
```

Where '#map' is the ID of the DIV where we put the map, and "options" is an object containing the map initialization options.

Now, let's explain what I want. I want to change the entire class structure of the GIS API. I want to have classes like:
* xgis (main class)
* xgis.map (map class)
* xgis.layer (layer class)
etc

It is working except for the widget. I wanted to initialize the map like this:

```
var newMap = xgis.map('#map', options);
```

As you can see, I want a simple way of initializing the map, thus hiding a bit the fact that it is a jQuery.ui widget.

Is it possible to change the widget structure so that this new initialization way works?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it directly with `$.widget`. But you can simply hide it. Create widgets using the normal API, with names like `xgis_map`, `xgis_layer`, etc., and then write a wrapper:

```
var xgis = {
    map: function(selector, options) {
        return $(selector).xgis_map(options);
    },
    layer: function(selector, options) {
        return $(selector).xgis_layer(options);
    },
    ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Barmar. It was so easy, but I didn't think about it. :) This is exactly what I wanted. Thanks!